# Inserting Drop-Down List in Table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have created a function to make a table from arrays of data which will resize according to the amount of data.

I would like to add a drop-down list to each row, but am having a problem getting it to appear. I know it is something simple, but I cannot find out what is happening.

The section in question is:

```
   for (var i = 1; i < chosenArray.length + 1; i++) {
         var thisRow = table.rows[i];
         var cell = thisRow.insertCell(columnCount - 1);
         cell.innerHTML = mySelectBox;
     }
```

I get the error: "ReferenceError: mySelectBox is not defined"

Full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/qamzen2k/12/

Any help would be welcomed!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `selectBox` rather than `mySelectBox`?

Comment: That just gives me [object HTMLSelectElement]

Comment: what do you want the text to be in `cell.innerHTML`?. There is no object called `mySelectBox`.

Comment: I don't want text, just the drop-down list.

Comment: I tried `selectBox.innerHTML` and got something. Try it; is that what you want? The reason you're getting the thing in the square brackets is because it doesn't know how to translate the `selectBox` object to actual html that it can put in the page.

Comment: Interesting: that gives me the contents of the drop-down list, but not the actual box.  It shows "Cheese" "0 1 2 3 4 5 6". (See https://jsfiddle.net/qamzen2k/)

Comment: Yes. That's what I got as well. What exactly do you want to put in that box? Can you show it outside of the box? What part of `selectBox` contains the HTML and so forth to actually create the drop-down list?

Comment: The list is just (in this case) the numbers from 0-6. in my actual application it might be filled with items from an array.

Comment: This is the section that fills the list:  var selectBox = document.createElement("Select")
    selectBox.name = "mySelectBox"
    selectBox.options[selectBox.options.length] = new Option("0", 0);
    selectBox.options[selectBox.options.length] = new Option("1", 1);
    selectBox.options[selectBox.options.length] = new Option("2", 2);
    selectBox.options[selectBox.options.length] = new Option("3", 3);
     etc.